# Adldap2-Laravel "Invalid credentials"

Tags: laravel, ldap

Making an AD integration on my "login" page.

config/ldap.php

my username and secrets are empty. (because everyone will make login on form)

```
'hosts' => explode(' ', env('LDAP_HOSTS', 'blabla')),
'base_dn' => env('LDAP_BASE_DN', 'dc=blabla,dc=com,dc=tr'),
'username' => env('LDAP_USERNAME', 'username'),
'password' => env('LDAP_PASSWORD', 'secret'),
```

ldap_auth.php

```
'sync_attributes' => [

    'email' => 'userprincipalname',

    'name' => 'cn',

],
```

auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'ldap',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

my authorization form function:

```
    $credentials = ['email' => $this->request['email'], 'password' => $this->request['password'], 'is_active' => 1];
    $remember = $this->request->has('remember');
    $results = array('status' => 0, "message" => "Unsuccesfull");
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $remember)) {
```

when I try to make login.
It returns;

```
"message": "Invalid credentials",
"exception": "Adldap\\Auth\\BindException",
"file": "/var/www/html/vendor/adldap2/adldap2/src/Auth/Guard.php",
"line": 107,
```

What could be wrong with it?
My LDAP LDAP_HOSTS and LDAP_BASE_DN informations are correct on .env file.

If it would be about my login information, it must return "username or password is invalid" but it returns "credentials are invalid" and I guess it must be about something else.

Comment: Always don't forget to restart your server after changings in .env